# Android Textview English + Arabic

Tags: android, textview

I have a normal Textview which contains both Arabic and English texts.

Below is the original text

```
"unit_label_text": "محتوى 0.4kg (€ 10.00 / 1Kg)",
```

When I try to paste it inside of xml it's like the below and the mobile app itself showing the same.

[image]

**Note: When the device language is English it's working fine. But if I changed the device language to Arabic. It's not working,**

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Arabic language the app automatically uses the `RTL` format so you can consider disabling the RTL (Right to Left) format for your app.

In your manifest file and inside the application tag add these two lines.

```
<manifest>
<application
    .
    .
    .
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
    >
</application>
```

Or else try removing this code from your XML

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Comment: Harsh I tried it's not working.     android:supportsRtl="false" won't help

Comment: remove the layoutDirection in your XML and also could show the screenshots of both scenarios? So it would be easy to detect the problem

Comment: Tried same issue.

Comment: Show the screenshot of both scenarios